# Where does Microsoft Edge Dev Channel check for NativeMessagingHosts on Windows 10?

Tags: microsoft-edge, chrome-native-messaging, microsoft-edge-extension

I tried adding the registry key on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Sotware\Microsoft\Edge Dev\NativeMessagingHosts\com.myapp.id` but when I try to connect to it, from my extension, I get this error

[Specified native messaging host not found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgQBY.png)

I already checked my manifest and it's properly pointing at the executable (with escaped `\` in the `path`) I also tried omitting the full path as the Microsoft documentation states that on Windows, I can use relative paths but no success there either.

This leads me to believe that maybe Edge is looking at a dfferent registry key but I don't know where.

To be clear, I am talking about the new Chromium-based Microsoft Edge, and not the older one that was restricted to UWP native messaging hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Apparently, Microsoft's documentation is wrong. It's still looking for the registry key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts` even with the official stable release.

Comment: I suggest you provide the document link that you are referring and you think that there is some mistake. We will try to review it and try to correct it. I also suggest you post your proper solution. It can be helpful to other users who have similar issues. As you had solved the issue. I suggest you mark your own answer. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I have added the key in ```HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts``` but it is not working for me.

Comment: sam,

I posted the solution to your issue on your other post.